# How do I rewrite mysite.com/page/ to mysite.com/page/index.html with NGINX?

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

How can I 301 rewrite mysite.com/page/ to mysite.com/page/index.html using nginx?

In Apache I had:

```
RewriteRule page/ http://mysite.com/page/index.html [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for help,

hydn

Comment: This was an issues with the back end PHP script. Once fixed the everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this settings:

```
location / {
    rewrite /page/ http://mysite.com/page/index.html permanent;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try. Including the ...?

Comment: Does the directory page exist? Try to put rewrite on a first line,and place try_files after that. And please provide query example, if it's possible

Comment: no that dir and index.html does not exists its friendly URLs. See below comments also

Answer (score 1):

I see from your comment to Sergiei that the '/page/' directory and '/page/index.html' does not actually exist and is rewritten elsewhere. So not surprising that Nginx gives a 404 not found.

What exactly should get served if a visitor requests '/page/index.html'? I.E., what does that get rewritten to?

If it is index.php?q=/page/index.html, then your config should be:

```
server {
    # index directive should be in server or http block
    # So no need to repeat in every location block
    # unless specifically overriding it
    index index.php index.html;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/page(/?)$ /page/index.html break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri;
    }
}
```

You could also use

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }
}
```

But there may be some issues with that. All depends on the detail of your application.